# filter: brightness won't override a grandparent component

Tags: html, css

Do you see the navbar? It looks ugly I know, I'll deal with it later. However, I want to ask about how I can make the navbar 100% brightness. I simply put 100% brightness on the class and it doesn't do anything. I'll post the code below

[image: The picture]

```css
bg-dark {
  filter: brightness(40%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
}

.mobileNav {
  color: rgb(150, 152, 166, 0.85);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  filter: brightness(100%);
}

.nav-items-mobile {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  /*     filter: brightness(100%); /* for some reason, this does not work */
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="navigation">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="Images/logo.svg" />
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-items-mobile">
        <li class="nav-li mobileNav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-li mobileNav"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-li mobileNav"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-li mobileNav"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="nav-li mobileNav"><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a id="invite" class="btn-nav" href="#">
        <button class="btn">Request Invite</button>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- I have other code below that I don't think is important. -->
</body>
```

Comment: Filters work differently than other CSS attributes. They combine rather than override. This is due to how filters work more than anything about CSS. To make your thing work, you'll need to make it so the element with brightness isn't an ancestor of the nav area.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see `bg-dark` class/id in your HTML, your code snippet is incomplete